# Why do I get an empty parameter on the controller in my HttpPost method Ajax call?

Tags: json, ajax, .net-core, http-post

I have a view that adds an Unordered list and list items to it at runtime, then I loop through to get the entered values, push the info to an object, and do the Ajax call to my method.

I always get an empty parameter on the controller, the `console.log(assetWeighJsonDetail)` shows what was entered, so I'm making sure I'm not passing and empty object (see the image below):

// Client side script:

```
var assetSerialNumber = "";
var weight = 0;
var assetWeighJsonDetail = [];

$(".ul-asset-weigh").each(function () {

    var classNameSelected = this.id;

    $("." + classNameSelected).each(function () {
        assetSerialNumber = $(this).attr('id');
        weight = $(this).val();
        assetWeighJsonDetail.push({
            OriginID: classNameSelected,
            AssetSerialNumber: assetSerialNumber,
            Weight: weight
        });
    });
});

console.log(assetWeighJsonDetail);

$.ajax({
    url: "/AssetWeigh/SaveAssetWeigh",
    data: JSON.stringify({assetWeighJsonDetail}),
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    traditional: true,
    success: function (response) {
        if (response) {
            alert("success");
        }
        else {
            alert("fail");
        }
    },
    error: function (exception) {
    }
});
```

// Console: 
[image: screenshot of console output]

// Controller Method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveAssetWeigh(List<AssetWeighJsonDetail> assetWeighJsonDetail)      
{
   bool success = false;

   success = assetWeighJsonDetail != null && assetWeighJsonDetail.Count > 0;

   return Json(success);
}
```

// Method's class List parameter:

```
public class AssetWeighJsonDetail
{
    public int OriginID { get; set; }
    public string AssetSerialNumber { get; set; }
    public decimal Weight { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Try without the curly brackets `data: JSON.stringify(assetWeighJsonDetail),`

Comment: @Musa, I've tried that already and doesn't work. The weird thing is that even if I try to pass a single value like data: { testStr: "Test-Str" } and change the method accordingly to: public ActionResult SaveAssetWeigh(string testStr) the parameter is null.

Comment: For the test string test did you change the content type from json?

Comment: Yes I did: data: "Test-Str",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "text",
        contentType: "text/plain",

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is sending the json in url-encoded form data `data: { assetWeighJsonDetail: JSON.stringify(assetWeighJsonDetail)},contentType:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',`

Comment: That didn't work either :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try with `$.post` I have faced the same issue if using `$.ajax` and was not working and just switching to `$.post` made it work.

```
$.post( "/AssetWeigh/SaveAssetWeigh", parameters, function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
 alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
 alert( "error" );
})
 .always(function() {
 alert( "finished" );
 });
```

I'm on my phone and can't type all of it, I'll try to update later from my computer

Comment: It worked! No need for JSON.stringify, the method took the parameter with no issues. You are the man, thanks!